# How to store data in localStorage in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rxjs, local-storage

I am trying to set up 2 types of users which are admin and anonymous and I am trying to store them in localStorage. So here, how I defined the account:

```
const [defaultAccount, setDefaultAccount] = useState(null, () => {
        const localData = localStorage.getItem('userType');
        return localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : [];
    });
```

And here is how I differentiate between admin and anonymous:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (defaultAccount === '') {
        localStorage.setItem('userType', 'admin')
        setConnButtonText('Wallet Connected');
    } else if (defaultAccount === '') {
        localStorage.setItem('userType', 'nonexist')
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('userType', 'anonymous')
        setConnButtonText('Wallet Connected');
    }
}, [defaultAccount])
```

But after I refreshed the page, even though I am an admin, it comes anonymous again. How can I fix this? So, to sum up, I click the button and get defaultAccount and I store userType as an admin. But then I refresh the page and it comes anonymous again. What I am trying to achieve, before the button is clicked, userType should be empty and after, it should be admin or anonymous. After refreshing the page, since it is stored in localStorage, it userType shouldnt be changed.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example of your code in codesandbox?

Comment: I am inspired from this project: https://github.com/mikec3/my_tutorials/tree/master/MetaMask_Connection the only difference inWalletCard.js and I added the code above

Comment: if (defaultAccount === '')       <------------ comparing to one condition, and in then
                                                                                                                                                       
    else if (defaultAccount === '')    <--------- comparing to the same condition here


In the if(){} and else if(){} statements, you are passing the same conditions, therefore, any other condition and the code jumps straight to the anonymous type. You might wanna fix that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide what `userType` will hold. There's a few issues:

1. `useState` *either* takes in an initial value, or a function that will evaluate the initial value. You are passing them both.
2. On the initial value function, `localStorage.getItem('userType')` seems like it returns a JSON object (you do JSON.parse), whereas you are `setItem('userType', 'some string')`
3. `useEffect` takes in an *array* of dependencies, you are passing in just the string `defaultAccount`
4. I don't fully understand what that `useEffect` does: `defaultAccount` comes from `userType`, but then it sets `userType` in the local storage *only* to `"admin"` or `"anonymous"`

Maybe something you're looking to do is something like:

```
const [defaultAccount, setDefaultAccount] = useState(() =>
  localStorage.getItem('userType') === 'admin' ? 'dgdsgd' : ''
)

useEffect(() => {
  if (defaultAccount === 'dgdsgd') {
    localStorage.setItem('userType', 'admin')
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('userType', 'anonymous')
  }
}, [defaultAccount])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I ask you one more thing? So I divided my user types to 3 (I edited my code in my question). Because when the button is not clicked, as a default I want to show that localStorage.getItem('userType') is non-exist. If the button is clicked according to defaultAccount, it can be admin or anonymous. How can I reah that?

Answer (score 0):

Your code always set initial value for defaultAccount is null